# System.Net.WebException remote name could not be resolved 'http'

Tags: c#, .net, networking, httpwebrequest

I am using `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` to make a request to a server by setting the proxy property of the object as:

```
webRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy("10.x.x.x", port);
```

it works fine but when I specify the https protocol:

```
webRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy("https://10.x.x.x", port);
```

it throws the error: `"System.Net.WebException remote name could not be resolved 'http'"`. Please note that even if I use 'https' protocol, in the exception it says `"remote name could not be resolved 'http'"`

is it something related to the networks settings on the requested server or something that I can handle while making the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the [`WebProxy(string, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsh37cx(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor - where the string is meant to be a *host name*, not a URI.

You should call the [`WebProxy(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2tt59d8(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, at which point the string is a URI. If you need to specify a non-default port, put that in the URI, e.g.

```
webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("https://10.1.1.1:12345");
```

Comment: Okay. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: One question though, if I continue using the constructor with host name and port number as parameters, will it be able to resolve the protocol?

Comment: @tavier: I don't believe so - the `Address` property would start with `http`. I don't know what the proxy code would do at that point, but I suspect it wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually our customer changed the configuration to remove https protocol from the url (so basically in code, we are now instantiating the WebProxy object by providing the host name (not url) and the port number) and they say that it works fine. So, is it okay to just provide the host name no matter what protocol server supports?

Comment: @tavier: No, I strongly suspect that's just a matter of their proxy supporting http as well as https. If it *only* supported https, I don't think that would work.

Comment: okay in that case I am going to change the code to use the other constructor (with url as parameter). Thanks @JonSkeet

Comment: just trying to avoid changing the code here and see if we can modify the config file to accommodate every scenario. So suppose if I continue using the same constructor with host name and port name and for those servers which support only https (as you said), if I provide the port number as 443, would it work?

Comment: @tavier: Again, I wouldn't expect so - see the third comment, which was my response to basically the same question. (But ideally, you should test all these things...)

Comment: okay, I thought since 443 is defaulted for secure http it may work. But if not, I have no other option but to change the code :) Thanks again @JonSkeet

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is networks settings. as i know, ip address 10.x.x.x is internal network ip.

Comment: yes, it's an internal network being used by one of our customers but we don't have any details about it. Is it possible to narrow it down to the specifics (like what kind of network settings etc)?

Comment: may be this server is not supporting https. You can ask admin or devOps who supported this server.

Comment: @AndrewRavkov: I don't believe that's the problem at all - see my answer.

Comment: I don't think this is really addressing the question - you'd *expect* a proxy to be an internal IP address. The problem is just putting the protocol at the front of the string, because the constructor being used expects the first parameter to be a host address, not a URI.